# Deploy ClickOnce Application from random locations

Tags: wpf, windows, deployment, clickonce

Having a WPF app we've got a server that lets the user to install using ClickOnce distribution. The issue here is the link we provide changes to hide real filesystem.

First time the user tries to install the app, everything goes well; the .application gets launched remotely and the app gets installed.

Next time the user wants to update the app, if the link provided is differente (because of a token or a differente sub-path) the user will receive a DeploymentException saying that the same app is already installed from a different location.

Is there a way to allow the app to be installed from any location we provide?

Thanks!

UPDATE 1:
Let me explain what we've got so far:
We have a web server that publishes a folder where the app lives. The path depends on some factors so it may change. if the user wants to install the same app from a different url path, it will fail.

Something like:

http://site.site/app_15/App.application

http://site.site/app_16/App.application

being app_15 and app_16 the same app but installed on different dates and admin sites.

Comment: Changing the installation/update paths is not a very good idea. If you want to hide the real installation path from the user, why don't you deploy to a web server and have the users install from an URL? You could configure IIS on the server that does the distribution already.

Comment: explanation updated above

Comment: you could try publishing the app with a different ProductName but then you'll have the app installed multiple times on a users PC

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that...